# How to make a progress bar with rounded corners in Xamarin Forms using Custom Renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, progress-bar, custom-renderer

I want to display progress bar with rounded corners in Xamarin forms. I was able to do it in iOS using a custom renderer:

```cs
class CustomProgressBarRenderer: ProgressBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.ProgressTintColor = Color.FromRgb(255, 201, 74).ToUIColor();
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        var X = 1.0f;
        var Y = 7.0f;
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(X, Y);
        this.Transform = transform;
        this.ClipsToBounds = true;
        this.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        this.Layer.CornerRadius = 5; // This is for rounded corners.
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same in Android using Custom Renderer.
This is how I want the progress bar(rounded corners) to look.

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the image when you use this `progress bar` in `iOS`,?only I know the effect can I understand what is you want.

Comment: I have added an image in my original post @YorkShen-MSFT

Answer (score 5):

> How to make a progress bar with rounded corners in Xamarin forms

You could add a `Drawable` on your android `ProgressBar` to implement this feature.

Set the style for your `ProgressBar` , **Drawable\bar_color.xml** :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--set progressbar backgound style-->
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar_background" />

    <!--set progressbar schedule style-->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/shape_progressbar_progress"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**Drawable\progress_bar_background.xml** :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFCBC2C2" />
</shape>
```

**Drawable\shape_progressbar_progress.xml** :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <corners android:radius="20dp" />
   <solid android:color="#3F8CC4" />
   <stroke
       android:width="0dp"
       android:color="#FFFFFF"></stroke>
</shape>
```

Using it in your `CustomProgressBarRenderer` :

```
public class CustomProgressBarRenderer : ProgressBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control != null)
        {
            var progressBar = Control as Android.Widget.ProgressBar;
            //below is now deprecated
            //var draw = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.bar_color);
            var draw = Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.bar_color);
            progressBar.ProgressDrawable = draw;
        }
    }
}
```

Effect :

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this using only custom renderers?