# How to create a progress bar with rounded corners in iOS using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I used inputs from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420739/how-to-make-a-progress-bar-with-rounded-corners-in-xamarin-forms) to create a custom progress-bar with rounded corners for the `Android` platform using the `Drawable`.
But the I'm not able to create the same output for the `iOS`.

Given below is how it looks on `Android`.
[image: Android Sample]

How can I create the same effect in the `iOS` as well?

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to do this, I prefer using the `CALayer` of a `UIView` and adding a `CAShapeLayer` that draws the "progress bar".

#### UIView ProgressBar Example:

[image]

```
public class ProgressView : UIView
{
    CAShapeLayer progressLayer;
    UILabel label;

    public ProgressView() { Setup(); }
    public ProgressView(Foundation.NSCoder coder) : base(coder) { Setup(); }
    public ProgressView(Foundation.NSObjectFlag t) : base(t) { Setup(); }
    public ProgressView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }
    public ProgressView(CGRect frame) : base(frame) { Setup(); }

    void Setup()
    {
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

        Layer.CornerRadius = 25;
        Layer.BorderWidth = 10;
        Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;
        Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan.CGColor;

        progressLayer = new CAShapeLayer()
        {
            FillColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor,
            Frame = Bounds
        };
        Layer.AddSublayer(progressLayer);

        label = new UILabel(Bounds)
        {
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
            TextColor = UIColor.White,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
            Font = UIFont.FromName("ChalkboardSE-Bold", 20)
        };
        InsertSubview(label, 100);
    }

    double complete;
    public double Complete
    {
        get { return complete; }
        set { complete = value; label.Text = $"{value * 100} %"; SetNeedsDisplay(); }
    }

    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        var progressWidth = (rect.Width - (Layer.BorderWidth * 2)) * complete;
        var progressRect = new CGRect(rect.X + Layer.BorderWidth, rect.Y + Layer.BorderWidth, progressWidth, (rect.Height - Layer.BorderWidth * 2));
        progressLayer.Path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(progressRect, 25).CGPath;
    }
}
```

#### Usage Example:

```
var progressView = new ProgressView(new CGRect(50, 50, 300, 50));
Add(progressView);
DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(async () =>
{
    while (progressView.Complete <= 1)
    {
        InvokeOnMainThread(() => progressView.Complete += 0.05);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. Could you also help me with how to implement this method using a `CustomRenderer` or with `Xamarin.Forms`?.

Comment: @LibinTK Xamarin has a guide that shows how to implemented a custom view renderer for Forms: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/

Comment: How to display same UI in android?

Comment: @Singapore Ask a new question with the code that you have so far and your issue.

Comment: @SushiHangoverThanks for this answer. I have used your answer to make a progress bar which starts from the right. 
`var progressWidth = (rect.Width - (Layer.BorderWidth * 2)) * (1 - complete);

 var progressRect = new CGRect(rect.X + progressWidth, rect.Y + Layer.BorderWidth, rect.Width - progressWidth, (rect.Height - Layer.BorderWidth * 2));

 progressLayer.Path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(progressRect, (UIRectCorner.TopRight | UIRectCorner.BottomRight), new CGSize(30, 30)).CGPath; `

But I don't see the label.

Comment: @Naman You should create a new question with the code you are using and the problem you are having

Comment: @SushiHangover I posted another question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938246/reverse-progress-bar-in-xamarin-forms