# Customizing a Progress Bar appearance in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I used `Drawable` to customize the rendering of the `ProgressBar` in `Android` as answered to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420739/how-to-make-a-progress-bar-with-rounded-corners-in-xamarin-forms) but the solution is not working with iOS.

Below is how it renders in `Android`.
[image]

Below is how it renders in `iOS`
[image]

Below is the code for my `iOS` `CustomRenderer`

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomProgressbar), typeof(CustomProgressBarRenderer))]
namespace Demo.iOS.Renderers
{
public class CustomProgressBarRenderer : ProgressBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ProgressBar> e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {                
               Control.ProgressTintColor = Color.FromHex("#ff0000").ToUIColor();                       
               Control.TrackTintColor = Color.FromHex("#3489cc").ToUIColor();
             } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        var X = 1.0f;
        var Y = 15.0f;
        CGAffineTransform _transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(X, Y);
        this.Transform = _transform;
        this.ClipsToBounds = true;
        this.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        this.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;
    }
}
```

}

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is cross-platform, what works in Android should also work in iOS. What have you tried so far, and what errors have you come across?

Comment: The question you referenced said:  > I was able to do it in iOS using a custom renderer

Comment: @MuhammadKhan yes, I followed the code mentioned in the question but it doesn't match the output. Let me add a screenshot from `iOS`.

Comment: @MuhammadKhan please see the edits

Comment: Are you using the **exact same code** as in the question you referenced? It looks like the sides have been smoothed rather than the `corner radius` set to 5. You will also have to set a border thickness/brush and change its colour too.

Comment: @MuhammadKhan I have added my `iOS` code. Could you please see it advise how to make changes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616422/how-to-create-a-progress-bar-with-rounded-corners-in-ios-using-xamarin-forms

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm still not able to figure out how to apply that in the custom renderer for the `ProgressBar`. Any input from you is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @LibinTK, have you solved your issue?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT yes, thank you so much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to @SushiHangover's answer, we can make a `ViewRenderer` to achieve your effect.

Firstly, create our own `ProgressView`, make sure it is inherited from `ContentView`. also add a `BindableProperty` to present the value:

```
public partial class ProgressView : ContentView
{
    public double Progress
    {
        set { SetValue(ProgressProperty, value); }
        get { return (double)GetValue(ProgressProperty); }
    }

    public readonly static BindableProperty ProgressProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Progress", typeof(double), typeof(ProgressView), 0.0);

    ...
}
```

Then, We can make the Custom renderer like:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    //You can refer to @SushiHangover's method for detail's code, here I use the same name.
    Setup();
    Complete = ((ProgressView)Element).Progress;
}

protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName == "Progress")
    {
        Complete = ((ProgressView)Element).Progress;
    }
}
```

Because this is in renderer, we should refresh our label's frame:

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    base.Draw(rect);
    ...
    label.Frame = Bounds;
}
```

At last we can use it on Forms like:

```
<local:ProgressView x:Name="MyProgress" HeightRequest="50"/>
```

Comment: I make a sample for you referring to: [https://github.com/lt0526/ProgressViewRendererDemo](https://github.com/lt0526/ProgressViewRendererDemo)