# How to create below type of custom progress bar in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms, progress-bar

How To develop this type of Design(I have attached image below)

[image]

Comment: Refer to this question answer also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703637/customizing-a-progress-bar-appearance-in-xamarin-forms

You can use syncfusion progress bar and its a third party component. https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/overview-of-the-progress-bar-control-in-xamarin-forms.aspx

Comment: You need to use custom renderer to change the style of progressbar or create a custom control to achieve what you want in the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposedly you are referring to the bars, not the overall layout, but it's not 100% clear from your question. While there are other possibilities to display the bars, I achieved quite a satisfying result by nesting an `AbsoluteLayout` in a frame. See the following example for one of the bars on the right

```xml
<Frame HasShadow="False" HeightRequest="20" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Silver" IsClippedToBounds="True">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,.33,1" 
                     BackgroundColor="CadetBlue">
            <Label Text="33%" 
                   FontSize="Small" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   TextColor="White" 
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
        </ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Frame>
```

The bar itself is wrapped by a `Frame` to get the rounded corners (see the `CornerRadius` property). Setting `IsClippedToBounds` to `true` is necessary, because otherwise the children won't be clipped and the rounded corners do not show.

Within the `Frame` there is the `AbsoluteLayout` the actual bars are placed in. And within, I added the dark-greenish bar as a `ContentView` (to be able to add a label with the percentage).

Please see the following code for one of the green/red bars. Basically it's the same, but I added two sub-bars within the absolute layout

```xml
<Frame HasShadow="False" HeightRequest="20" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Silver" IsClippedToBounds="True">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,.25,1"
                     BackgroundColor="LimeGreen">
            <Label Text="25%" 
                   FontSize="Small"  
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   TextColor="White" 
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
        </ContentView>
        <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,.75,1"
                     BackgroundColor="Red">
            <Label Text="75%" 
                   FontSize="Small" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   TextColor="White" 
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
        </ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Frame>
```

### Generalization

It'd be useful to extract a re-usable component. I will show for the simpler bar. Transferring the solution to the more complex one should be easy, though.

#### Code behind

In the code behind the following properties have to be added

```cs
public Rectangle FirstBarBounds => new Rectangle(0, 0, BarValue, 1);

public double BarValue
{
    get => this._barValue;
    set
    {
        if (this._barValue == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        this._barValue = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

(Adding a `BindableProperty` for `BarValue` could be useful, too, but admittedly I was too lazy.)

The properties can be bound to from XAML

```
<Frame ...>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{Binding FirstBarBounds}"
                     BackgroundColor="CadetBlue" >
            <Label Text="{Binding FirstBarValue, StringFormat='{}{0:P0}'}" 
                   FontSize="Small" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                   TextColor="White" 
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
        </ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Frame>
```

The `LayoutBounds` of the `ContentView` is bound to `BarBounds` (which in turn uses `BarValue` to determine the bounds of the bar) and the text is bound to `BarValue`. Since `BarValue` is a double, the value is formatted to a percentage by `StringFormat='{}{0:P0}'`.

### Screenshot

Please see the following screen shot on how the bars are rendered on an Android device (Emulator).

[image: Image displaying the bars]

Comment: `StringFormat='{}{0:0%}'` for anyone who doesn't want a space between the number and percent symbol.