# How to create graph in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, graph

How can I get a graph like this in Xamarin?
Is there any library for graphs or how is this done?
I have this but I want to style it like in the picture.

```
<ProgressBar ProgressColor="#00d2ff" HeightRequest="20" Progress="0.5"/>
```

[image]

Comment: that appears to be a progress bar, not a graph.  You can easily build that from standard XF elements.  If you need complex charts, https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+charts&oq=xamarin+charts

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are looking for help building you own progress bar or chart, please show us what you've tried so far. Asking for a third party library to solve your problem is off-topic on SO, see [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thanks i have meant progress bar but i want to style it like in picture and i dont know how i have this code `<ProgressBar ProgressColor="#00d2ff" HeightRequest="20" Progress="0.5"/>`

Comment: the standard progress bar is not going to look like what you want.  As I said earlier, you can easily build this by layering two BoxViews on top of each other with a Label on top of both

Comment: Ah thanks i will try that and send code if it going to work :)

Comment: It is not looking good with my progress bar i will use default progress bar, thanks for help

Comment: @JacobBat Hi, if you mean want to customer a progressbar, you could have a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703637/customizing-a-progress-bar-appearance-in-xamarin-forms/48742799

Comment: Thanks, but i have used default progress bar

Comment: @JacobBat Then it seems you will need to custom `ProgressBarRenderer` to achieve that with navtive method of each platform.