# How to create progress bar with rounded corners / Edge in Xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, progress-bar, custom-renderer

I need the expert help. I am struggling to create the ProgressBar with rounded corner in Xamarin Form. I have searched on google and found the couple of post by using the layer property ex. "Layer.CornerRadius = 5" but my code does not support it.

[How to make a progress bar with rounded corners in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420739/how-to-make-a-progress-bar-with-rounded-corners-in-xamarin-forms).

(The above example not supported)

How can I create the rounded Edge of the progress bar?

Sample Code (TestControls.xaml usnig XamarinForm):-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Mobile"
            xmlns:ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
             x:Class="Test.Mobile.UI.TestControls">
    <ContentPage.Content>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1"  Margin="0" Padding="0"  BackgroundColor= "LightYellow"  >
                <ProgressBar x:Name="pb_ProgressBar" Margin="70,0,30,0"   Progress="0.0" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="20" ProgressColor="DarkSlateBlue" VerticalOptions="Center"  BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite"></ProgressBar>
            </Grid> 

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and Code behind file as

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Test.Mobile.UI
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TestControls : ContentPage
    {
        public TestControls ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await pb_ProgressBar.ProgressTo(1.0, 10000, Easing.Linear);
            });
        }         

    }
}
```

[image]

Please help me how to make a progress bar with rounded corners in Xamarin forms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a progress bar with rounded corners in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420739/how-to-make-a-progress-bar-with-rounded-corners-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: The example you linked should work fine. Did you create a custom renderer in both the iOS and Android projects? The customer iOS renderer is where the `Layer.CornerRadius=5` is being set, not in the code behind of the view.

Comment: I am using for Android initially. For that Layer.CornerRadius property is not supported. INfect Layer is not supported.  How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Check out the first (and only) answer in the question you linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46450550/8395242

Comment: I can not use the code at stackoverflow.com/a/46450550/8395242 in my code because of the library.

Comment: What library? I don't see a library in the linked answer, and the only library you have posted in your code is FFImageLoading, which isn't even used in your example.

Comment: I can not use xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android". The device android tablet will be use offline and no internet access. Its communicating with some other hardware device by Bluetooth.

Comment: @skt, have you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I can not use xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";. The device android tablet will be use offline and no internet access.

This is not library, you could refer to the question:

[Why this line xmlns:android=“http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android” must be the first in the layout xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119359/why-this-line-xmlnsandroid-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-must-be)

As NitroG42 said, in `XML`, `xmlns` declares a Namespace. In fact, when you do:

```
<LinearLayout android:id>
</LinearLayout>
```

Instead of calling `android:id`, the `xml` will use `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:id` to be unique. Generally this page doesn't exist (**it's a `URI`, not a `URL`**), but sometimes it is a `URL` that explains the used namespace.

The namespace has pretty much the same uses as the package name in a Java application.

You could refer to the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp):

> Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)
>
> A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a string of characters which identifies an Internet Resource.
>
> The most common `URI` is the Uniform Resource Locator (URL) which identifies an Internet domain address. Another, not so common type of URI is the Universal Resource Name (URN).